# Angular 2+ custom directive for a input element - how to detect a reset call

Tags: angular, input, angular2-directives

I built a custom directive for input elements. It is a search directive that given an items input returns an output with these items filtered based on the search string.

```
<input pieSearch placeholder='Search' [attribute]='"label"' [formControl]='search'
        [items]='widgetOfSelectedType' (filterEvent)='filterWidgets($event)'>
```

Under the hood, I am simply using a Hostlistener and then calling a pipe. As such:

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event.target.value']) onKeyUp(value) {
  this.searchTerm = value;
  this.applyFilter();
}
```

That works well for everything expect when I want to reset my input `this.search.reset()`. Which makes sense, as this isn't a user typing in the input field it isn't caught by the Hostlistener.

So my question to you all, is how would you go about doing that?

Comment: You can implement the event **change** for this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple resetSpy directive for you. You can inject NgControl directive to get access to the underlying FormControl directive.

Then it's just a matter of creating our own reset stream. We are mapping the form value changes to its pristine status. If the control goes from not pristine to pristine, it means that the form was reset.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reset-spy-directive)

```
import { Directive, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {map, pairwise, startWith, filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[resetSpy]',
})
export class ResetSpyDirective  {
  @Output() reset = new EventEmitter<void>();

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const reset$ = this.ngControl.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      map(v => this.ngControl.pristine),
      startWith(this.ngControl.pristine),
      pairwise(),
      filter(([from, to]) => !from && to)
    );

    this.subscription = reset$.subscribe(() => this.reset.emit());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort of creating this directive. In the end, I am going to do something slightly different. I am going to replace my `HostListener` with your `ngControl.control.valueChanges`. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad I could help :)